# 1-form on the sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $F(x,y,z)=(x,y^2,z^3)$, define a 1-form on $S^2$ by $\eta(X_p)= <F,X_p>$. Let $q=(1/2, 1/2 , 1/sqrt(2))$ and $X_q=(1,-1,0)$,$Y_q=(0,2,-sqrt(2))$. Find $d\eta(X_q,Y_q)$.Thanks.